# Excel error - Spacial character display as 0

Tags: php, excel

I am getting an issue in excel data. I have some code in PHP. This code extract data in an excel file. In one column I am getting '0' value, which is wrong. The actual data is '@GTQ$/X0st'.

I am struggling through it. I don't know how could I solve this issue.

Here is my function:

```
function user_download_xls($userids, $fields, $includecompanyfield) {
    global $CFG, $SESSION, $DB;

    require_once("$CFG->libdir/excellib.class.php");
    require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/user/profile/lib.php');

    $filename = clean_filename(get_string('users').'.xls');

    $workbook = new MoodleExcelWorkbook('-');
    $workbook->send($filename);

    $worksheet = array();

    $worksheet[0] = $workbook->add_worksheet('');
    $col = 0;
    foreach ($fields as $fieldname) {
        if ($includecompanyfield || $fieldname != "profile_field_company") {
            $worksheet[0]->write(0, $col, $fieldname);
            $col++;
        }
    }
    $worksheet[0]->write(0, $col, 'temppassword');

    $row = 1;
    foreach ($userids as $userid) {
        // Stop the script from timing out on large numbers of users.
        set_time_limit(30);
        if (!$user = $DB->get_record('user', array('id' => $userid))) {
            continue;
        }
        $col = 0;
        profile_load_data($user);
        foreach ($fields as $field => $unused) {
            // Stop the script from timing out on large numbers of users.
            set_time_limit(30);
            if ($includecompanyfield || $field != "profile_field_company") {
                $worksheet[0]->write($row, $col, $user->$field);
                $col++;
            }
        }
       $tempcode =  company_user::get_temporary_password($user);

       $worksheet[0]->write($row, $col, $tempcode);

        $row++;
    }
    //exit;

    $workbook->close();
    die;
}
```

My column is populating from this step -  $worksheet[0]->write($row, $col, mb_convert_encoding($tempcode));

I tried all google steps, Listed here:
- utf8_decode
- htmlspecialchars
- mb_convert_encoding

Update: After debugging I found the spacial character prevent to display correct data. `@` is at first position converting data into 0. I think I convert data as a calculation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: utf8_decode or utf8_encode which one you use? Because If your text is not encoded in  ISO-8859-1, you do not need this function. If your text is already in UTF-8, you do not need this utf8_encode function.

Comment: @Nawin, Yeah you are right. If you have any idea to solve this, please let me know. Thanks